# Get process name by PID

Tags: python, process, pid

This should be simple, but I'm just not seeing it.

If I have a process ID, how can I use that to grab info about the process such as the process name.

Comment: @PeterO. That question is the **reverse** of this one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Under Linux, you can read proc filesystem. File `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` contains the commandline.

Comment: An alternative is `ps -o cmd= <pid>`.

Comment: And `/proc/<pid>/comm` actually gives the process name.

Answer (score 15):

Try PSUtil -> https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil

Works fine on Windows and Unix, I recall.

Comment: That seems like the right thing to do.  It bugs me that it's not in debian 5 however.

Comment: That's a (common) problem with debian, not with psutil ;)

Comment: you can just "python setup.py install" to install it from sources.

Comment: I agree with you both, and it's something I would have done if it were on a particular server, but it's for an application that we're distributing that still only supports debian 5 at this time ;) .  Reading /proc will just be easier and more reliable for us to manage in the long run.

Comment: I am using p.name() which is truncating the output. Is there any other way to get the complete process name??

Answer (score 3):

For Windows

A Way to get all the pids of programs on your computer without downloading any modules:

```
import os

pids = []
a = os.popen("tasklist").readlines()
for x in a:
      try:
         pids.append(int(x[29:34]))
      except:
           pass
for each in pids:
         print(each)
```

If you just wanted one program or all programs with the same name and you wanted to kill the process or something:

```
import os, sys, win32api

tasklistrl = os.popen("tasklist").readlines()
tasklistr = os.popen("tasklist").read()

print(tasklistr)

def kill(process):
     process_exists_forsure = False
     gotpid = False
     for examine in tasklistrl:
            if process == examine[0:len(process)]:
                process_exists_forsure = True
     if process_exists_forsure:
         print("That process exists.")
     else:
        print("That process does not exist.")
        raw_input()
        sys.exit()
     for getpid in tasklistrl:
         if process == getpid[0:len(process)]:
                pid = int(getpid[29:34])
                gotpid = True
                try:
                  handle = win32api.OpenProcess(1, False, pid)
                  win32api.TerminateProcess(handle, 0)
                  win32api.CloseHandle(handle)
                  print("Successfully killed process %s on pid %d." % (getpid[0:len(prompt)], pid))
                except win32api.error as err:
                  print(err)
                  raw_input()
                  sys.exit()
    if not gotpid:
       print("Could not get process pid.")
       raw_input()
       sys.exit()

   raw_input()
   sys.exit()

prompt = raw_input("Which process would you like to kill? ")
kill(prompt)
```

That was just a paste of my process kill program I could make it a whole lot better but it is okay.

Answer (score 2):

Using psutil, here is the simplest code i can give you:

```
import psutil

# The PID ID of the process needed
pid_id = 1216

# Informations of the Process with the PID ID
process_pid = psutil.Process(pid_id)
print(process_pid)
# Gives You PID ID, name and started date
# psutil.Process(pid=1216, name='ATKOSD2.exe', started='21:38:05')

# Name of the process
process_name = process_pid.name()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def filter_non_printable(str):
    ret=""
    for c in str:
        if ord(c) > 31 or ord(c) == 9:
            ret += c
        else:
            ret += " "
    return ret

#
# Get /proc/<cpu>/cmdline information
#
def pid_name(self, pid):
    try:
        with open(os.path.join('/proc/', pid, 'cmdline'), 'r') as pidfile:
            return filter_non_printable(pidfile.readline())

    except Exception:
        pass
        return
```