# Process name from its pid in linux

Tags: c, linux, process, system, pid

How to get a process name from his pid ?
For example I execute cat file1.txt, but I want to figure out that cat command and its arguments since its pid in the system. Is there a struct to determine it or something similar? Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get process name by PID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189717/get-process-name-by-pid)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is not any general way to do this unix. 
Each OS has different ways to handle it and some are very hard. You mention Linux though. With Linux, the info is in the /proc filesystem. 
To get the command line for process id 9999, read the file `/proc/9999/cmdline`.

Comment: And to get the process name for process id 9999, read the file `/proc/9999/comm`.

Comment: The question was how to get the process name, not the commandline.  On my SUSE I enter 'head  /proc/9999/cmdline' for a kwrite process and it returns: 'kdeinit4: kwrite [kdeinit]'. If I use /comm instead of /cmdline I get the correct result: 'kwrite'.

Comment: `/proc/$pid/comm` trims the output to 15 chars, it seems. This is very... very bad...

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou `/proc/<PID>/comm` will be truncated if it reaches 16 chars or TASK_COMM_LEN,
a better way is to read `realpath` of `/proc/<PID>/exe`

as shown [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/629871/505340)

Answer (score 16):

On linux, you can look in `/proc/`.  Try typing `man proc` for more information. The contents of `/proc/$PID/cmdline` will give you the command line that process `$PID` was run with. There is also `/proc/self` for examining yourself :)

An alternative (e.g. on Mac OS X) is to use `libproc`. See [libproc.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dtrace/dtrace-90/libproc/libproc.h).

Comment: Can you please tell me the difference between your answer and mine? :)

Comment: Your answer wasn't there when I started writing mine :)

Answer (score 15):

POSIX C does NOT support give a standard API for getting the process name by PID.

In linux, you can get the name by LINUX Proc API: /proc/$PID/cmdline. And the code looks like these:

```
const char* get_process_name_by_pid(const int pid)
{
    char* name = (char*)calloc(1024,sizeof(char));
    if(name){
        sprintf(name, "/proc/%d/cmdline",pid);
        FILE* f = fopen(name,"r");
        if(f){
            size_t size;
            size = fread(name, sizeof(char), 1024, f);
            if(size>0){
                if('\n'==name[size-1])
                    name[size-1]='\0';
            }
            fclose(f);
        }
    }
    return name;
}
```

Comment: And if you came here looking for a solution in C# working with mono, then have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827331/workaround-for-bug-in-mono-wrong-process-processname-solved

Answer (score 13):

To get the process name of a process id say 9000 use this command:

```
ps -p 9000 -o comm=
```

Answer (score 3):

While this question has been answered, I'd like to add my 2 cents.

In my case, when process `1111` creates process `22222` via `pipe` (at least this is what I heard), `/proc/2222/cmdline` does not give correct process name, but instead gives something like `1111_1`. I have to use `/proc/2222/comm` to get the correct process name.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below command in Linux

```sh
ls -l /proc/[pid]/exe
```

It will give the name of the process/application name

Answer (score 1):

`ps --pid <pid> -o comm h` :
This command gives executable file name. For example if you run a script name.sh, then the above command gives output as `bash`

`ps --ppid <pid> -o comm h`:
This command gives the output as `name`