# Workaround for bug in mono: Wrong Process.ProcessName

Tags: c#, linux, mono

If you work with mono and use `Process.ProcessName` you may get wrong results on some computers.

For example instead of the process name "`kwrite`" you may get "`kdeinit4`" (seen on SUSE).

On Ubuntu I have even seen complete bullshit like "`kdeinit4;5535948c (deleted)`" instead of "`kwrite`".

Note: On other computers the result may be correct.

If I use `Process.MainModule.ModuleName` it retruns the same wrong name.
And if I use `Process.MainModule.FileName` it gives the wrong path. Apart from that these commands are EXTREMELY slow.

So whatever I try it is full of bugs.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround can be done with two lines:

```
String sProcFile = String.Format("/proc/{0}/comm", proc.Id);
String sProcName = File.ReadAllText(sProcFile).Trim();
```

It works like a charm on all computers where `ProcessName` fails.