# What is the best way to get the application name if you have the process id on linux?

Tags: linux

What is the best way to get the application name when you already have the process id?

Comment: Best way would be to ask this kind of question at [Super User](https://superuser.com/), where it belongs.

Comment: duplicate of : http://superuser.com/questions/632979/if-i-know-the-pid-number-of-a-process-how-can-i-get-its-name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get process name by PID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189717/get-process-name-by-pid)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ps`:

```
ps -p 1337 -o comm=
```

Where `-p` is for pid and `-o` for the output format.