# Get the process name by pid

Tags: python, linux

I have a python program. It stores a variable called "pid" with a given pid of a process. First of all I need to check that the process which owns this pid number is really the process I'm looking for and if it is I need to kill it from python. So first I need to check somehow that the name of the process is for example "pfinder" and if it is pfinder than kill it. I need to use an old version of python so I can't use psutil and subprocess. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: `os.system("killall pfinder")`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189717/get-process-name-by-pid

Comment: os.system does not work because it kills all the processes with that name, not just the one which needs to be killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly obtain this information from the `/proc` file system if you don't want to use a separate library like [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil).

```
import os
import signal

pid = '123'
name = 'pfinder'

pid_path = os.path.join('/proc', pid)
if os.path.exists(pid_path):
    with open(os.join(pid_path, 'comm')) as f:
        content = f.read().rstrip('\n')

    if name == content:
         os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

> ```
>    /proc/[pid]/comm (since Linux 2.6.33)
>           This file exposes the process's comm value—that is, the
>           command name associated with the process.  Different threads
>           in the same process may have different comm values, accessible
>           via /proc/[pid]/task/[tid]/comm.  A thread may modify its comm
>           value, or that of any of other thread in the same thread group
>           (see the discussion of CLONE_THREAD in clone(2)), by writing
>           to the file /proc/self/task/[tid]/comm.  Strings longer than
>           TASK_COMM_LEN (16) characters are silently truncated.
>
>           This file provides a superset of the prctl(2) PR_SET_NAME and
>           PR_GET_NAME operations, and is employed by
>           pthread_setname_np(3) when used to rename threads other than
>           the caller.
> ```