# How can I get process name using Python

Tags: python, windows

I know I can get processId by GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd) like ,

```
pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
```

but , how can I use pid to get process name (ex: chrome.exe,explorer.exe...etc)

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get process name by PID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189717/get-process-name-by-pid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the win32 modules so you could do:

```
import win32api
import win32process
import win32con

.....

pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
handle = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | win32con.PROCESS_VM_READ, False, pid[1])
proc_name = win32process.GetModuleFileNameEx(handle, 0)
```

By the way, it's done in the following:
http://nullege.com/codes/show/src%40f%40p%40fpdb-sql-HEAD%40pyfpdb%40WinTables.py/135/win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId/python
For a cross platform solution I would probably try to use psutil as mentioned by others already.  You can also look the following:
https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/10/03/how-to-find-and-list-all-running-processes-with-python/

Comment: Thanks a lot , and the links help me more info .

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to use a 3rd party module, you can do this easily with [`psutil`](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil)

First you need to install it:

```
pip install psutil
```

Then, assuming you have a process ID aready, you just need to do this:

```
import psutil
PID = 5220
print(psutil.Process(PID).name())
```

In my case, this prints:

```
python.exe
```

Comment: thanks , I know psutil is good to use, then, I will use win32process to solve.